# Help with NHibernate Criteria query groupby property

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, nhibernate-projections

I have the below query,

```
SearchTemplate Template = new SearchTemplate();
            Template.Criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(table1));

            Template.Criteria.CreateCriteria("table2", "Usr", NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)

                 .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
                 .Add(Projections.Count("Usr.ID"), "UserCount")
                  .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Location"), "ALocation")
                  .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Company"), "ACompany")
                  .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Usr.Designation"), "ADesignation"));
```

The above query gives me data as,

```
Location   Company    Designation   Count
  Florida      A          Manager       3
  Florida      A          QA            5
  Texas        B          Manager       6
  Texas        B          QA            7
```

Is there a way to change the query so that it gives data as,

```
  Location   Company    Manager    QA               
  Florida      A           3       5
  Texas        B           6       7
```

Here Manager and QA are the only possible values that can go into Designation field..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
.Add(Projections.Count("Usr.ID"), "UserCount")
.Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Usr.Designation"), "ADesignation")
```

You'll need two projections, one per result column:

```
.Add(Projections.Sum(Projections.Conditional(
                                 Restrictions.Eq("Usr.Designation", "Manager"),
                                 Projections.Constant(1),
                                 Projections.Constant(0)))
.Add(Projections.Sum(Projections.Conditional(
                                 Restrictions.Eq("Usr.Designation", "QA"),
                                 Projections.Constant(1),
                                 Projections.Constant(0)))
```

Comment: I bow before your knowledge +1